# Two equivalent Erlang distributions with the same mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

According to Wikipedia ([Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Properties)),

- If $ X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k, \lambda)$ then $ a \cdot X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}\left(k, \frac{\lambda}{a}\right)$ with $ a \in \mathbb{R}$
- If $ X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k_1, \lambda)$ and $ Y \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k_2, \lambda)$ then $ X + Y \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k_1 + k_2, \lambda)$

From the above two statements, can we claim, if $p$ is a natural number, then $ \sum_{i=1}^{p} X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(p \cdot k, \lambda)$ is equivalent to $ p \cdot X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k, \lambda/p)$

Comment: Does $\sum_{i=1}^{p} X$ mean the sum of $p$ independent and identically distributed samples from the distribution of $X$? Or does it mean the sum of $p$ identically valued copies of a sample from the distribution of $X$?

Comment: The sum of $p$ independent and identically distributed samples from the distribution of $X$

Comment: Then I would have thought $\sum_{i=1}^{p} X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(p \cdot k, \lambda)$ is equivalent to $X \sim \operatorname{Erlang}( k, \lambda)$ and you can apply the first point

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.